# How to protect non-metallic cable entering a sub panel

Tags: electrical, subpanel, nec

I have this sub panel I'm considering replacing. What do I do with the exposed Romex to pass inspection? Some kind of cable trough maybe?

[image: sub panel in basement closet]

Comment: Interesting question.  Romex and similar cables need protection below 8 feet if not in a wall, but every panel picture with romex is the same as yours.  The romex going to that switch/s is the problem area.  The free/clear space in front and to side of the panel might be a problem.  That drain pipe might be in the way, maybe that wall/corner also.

Comment: I would do plywood on standoffs, screwed not nailed for easy access in the future.

Comment: The drain is clearly in the working space, and the apparent dryer vent is a bit suspect location-wise, too.

Answer (score 1):

Square plastic conduit (with zip-lok like lid)

Or you can just put a stud or partial stud and attach it to the side of the stud or the existing wall .

> Between exposed joists or studs, provided the cables are recessed away from the face of the framing members.

Also, that switch needs a face plate.